# Project Server 2010 site creation - the database connection string is not available

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-project

I am trying to get Project Server 2010 up and running on a Win Server 2008 box. I've got Sharepoint 2010 installed and Project Server 2010 installed. I open SharePoint Central Administration, then I go to Manage Service Applications > Project Server Service Application. It looks like there is a site under the "Sharepoint - 80" section, but the Status says "Failed - see the Application event Log". When I click on the site and select "Retry" I get the same thing. In the event viewer, I see an error with SharePoint Foundation Search as the Source - it reads:

> Could not create a database session.
>
> Context: Application
>   '276504a6-93b1-4c1f-a900-fd6ed9d5c117'
>
> Details:  The database connection
>   string is not available.   (0xc0041228)

How can I fix this? Is there some configuration I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there were some databases that already existed in the SharePoint database instance, and I wondered if the project site creation process was getting messed up because they were already there. I deleted the default instance of the project web app, then created a new one, and this actually worked. Hope this helps someone in the future.